# php IF / ELSEIF inside IF / ELSEIF

Tags: php, if-statement

Hi there I have the following php that I have been developing

```
<?php

$URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$activepage = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];

if (
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "facebookexternalhit/") !== false ||          
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Facebot") !== false
) {
    // it is probably Facebook's bot
    if ($activepage=="www.example.co.uk") {
    $link = 'http://www.example.co.uk' . $URI;
    header("location:$link");
    exit;
    }
    elseif ($activepage=="test.example.co.uk") {
    $link = 'http://test.example.co.uk' . $URI;
    header("location:$link");
    exit;
    }
    elseif ($activepage=="www.example.us") {
    $link = 'http://www.example.us' . $URI;
    header("location:$link");
    exit;
    }

}
elseif {
    // that is not Facebook
    if ($activepage=="test.example.co.uk" & $country_code=="CA") {
    $link = 'http://www.example.us' . $URI;
    header("location:$link");
    exit;
    }
    elseif ($activepage=="test.example.co.uk" & $country_code=="US") {
    $link = 'http://www.example.us' . $URI;
    header("location:$link");
    exit;
    }
    elseif ($activepage=="test.example.us" & $country_code=="GB") {
    $link = 'http://www.example.co.uk' . $URI;
    header("location:$link");
    exit;
    }
    elseif ($activepage=="test.example.us" & $country_code=="UK") {
    $link = 'http://www.example.co.uk' . $URI;
    header("location:$link");
    exit;
    }

}



?>
```

the second if / elseif works fine which by itself looks like this

```
<?php

$URI = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
$activepage = $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
$country_code = $_SERVER["HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY"];

if ($activepage=="www.example.co.uk" & $country_code=="CA") {
$link = 'http://www.example.us' . $URI;
header("location:$link");
exit;
}
elseif ($activepage=="www.example.co.uk" & $country_code=="US") {
$link = 'http://www.example.us' . $URI;
header("location:$link");
exit;
}
elseif ($activepage=="www.example.us" & $country_code=="GB") {
$link = 'http://www.example.co.uk' . $URI;
header("location:$link");
exit;
}
elseif ($activepage=="www.example.us" & $country_code=="UK") {
$link = 'http://www.example.co.uk' . $URI;
header("location:$link");
exit;
}

?>
```

However when I pop it inside this

```
if (
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "facebookexternalhit/") !== false ||          
    strpos($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"], "Facebot") !== false
) {
    // it is probably Facebook's bot
}
else {
    // that is not Facebook
}
```

it stops working all together.

what I want to do is have it so facebook bot goes to the site which the link is used however failing this if it is a normal user, then if a user from US hits the UK site they're redirected and if a user from the UK gets the US site they get redirected - using cloudflares HTTP headers.

Any thoughts on where I might be going wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Please tag appropriately. Your issue is not about what the `facebook`, `robot` or `google-crawler` tag are supposed to be used for. You have a basic PHP syntax/control flow logic problem.

Answer (score 0):

You have an `elseif` with no condition in your first listing, this should probably be just `else`

```
}
elseif {
    // that is not Facebook
```

Should be

```
}
else {
    // that is not Facebook
```

Answer (score 0):

Your else if statements are not correct. Please see http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php

```
// it is probably Facebook's bot

if ( $activepage=="www.example.co.uk" ) {

    $link = 'http://www.example.co.uk' . $URI;
    header( "location:$link" );
    exit;

} elseif( $activepage=="test.example.co.uk" ) {

    $link = 'http://test.example.co.uk' . $URI;
    header("location:$link");
    exit;

} elseif( $activepage=="www.example.us" ) {

    $link = 'http://www.example.us' . $URI;
    header("location:$link");
    exit;

} else {

    //you need to do something here

}
```

If you're planning on keeping `elseif( $activepage=="www.example.us" ) {` then you need to add an else statement just like I have added into the answer.

Otherwise you can change `elseif( $activepage=="www.example.us" ) {` to `else( $activepage=="www.example.us" ) {`

You also have a syntax error in the second part of your if statement.

**This is what you have**

```
   elseif ( $activepage=="test.example.us" & $country_code=="UK" ) {
       $link = 'http://www.example.co.uk' . $URI;
       header("location:$link");
       exit;
   }
```

You need to either change that to `else ( $activepage=="test.example.us" & $country_code=="UK" )` or have it look like below

```
   elseif ($activepage=="test.example.us" & $country_code=="UK") {
        $link = 'http://www.example.co.uk' . $URI;
        header("location:$link");
        exit;

    } else {

        //do something here 

    }
```

You also have a syntax error on your main if statement.

**This is what you have**

```
}elseif {
    // that is not Facebook
```

**This is what it needs to be**

```
}else {
    // that is not Facebook
```